# canOpenURL doesnt seem to be working in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I cant figure what I am doing wrong in swift. I am using the below code on an ipad and every time it returns true for the if statement. The same/similar code is working in objective c

**my code:**

```
phoneNumber = "5155555555"
var url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: "tel://" + phoneNumber)

if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!)) {
   //do stuff
```

**objective C** (this works as expected)

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]]) {
```

Comment: Are you running iOS 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems here.

One, you create an incorrect `NSURL` object in the Objective C version, which is why it returns false.

Now, iPad applications return true when asked if can open telephone URLs because iPad can and does use FaceTime to make calls. To test this, disable FaceTime on your iPad and see that the answer in this case will be negative.

Comment: I disabled facetime and no change. still passes the if statement

Comment: Do you have handoff enabled? This can also be used to make calls through your phone.

Why are you fighting the system? If it tells you it can make a call, it can. If you need a specific logic to not run on iPads, then use different means to determine that.

Comment: Im not trying to fight the system, the issue is after I do the check I then call `            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
` which does nothing on the ipad